# I don't Understand how to exist task in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have made a file named CHECKPRODUCT.CMD. But I have another file that runs at startup and it is named ACTIVATED.cmd. But I don't understand how to exists task ACTIVATED.cmd in CHECKPRODUCT.cmd. Like I tried this examples:

```
if tasklist == "ACTIVATED.cmd" (
goto :1 ) else (
goto :2 )
```

but, it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tasklist to check many facets of tasks running and the OLD school training was give your bat files a title for exactly this reason.

[image]

First always ensure (and I often forget) use Title in a bat or cmd that is likely to not exit quickly its useful for tasklist as here and on occasion taskkill /t or considered bad if you use /F. Try to use a unique name otherwise editing activate.cmd can show up in notepad **and** cmd

```
@echo off & title ACTIVATED
echo Running Activated
pause
```

You can use other status tests than "running" see `tasklist /?`

```
tasklist /FI "WindowTitle eq ACTIVATED" /FI "STATUS eq running" |  Find /i "cmd"
REM bad find=2    not found=1   found at least once=0
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
echo true) else (
echo false)
pause
```

You may need to use `....ACTIVATED*"` if you want to test for multiple entries etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you're trying to determine if another batch file is still running from another.

You can do that by checking the command line strings of running cmd.exe processes, using the WMI command line utility.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "ScriptName=ACTIVATED.cmd"

%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Where^
 "Name='cmd.exe' And CommandLine Like '%%%ScriptName:_=[_]%%%'"^
 Get ProcessId /Value 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "=" 1>NUL^
 || GoTo :2

:1
Echo %ScriptName% is running.
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:2
Echo %ScriptName% is not running.
Pause
```

Note: Whilst you're free to modify the script name on line `4`, please be aware that this would need additional work, should you decide to use file names containing `[`, `]`, `^`, or `%` characters.